# Adding a comma after $variable

Tags: bash, whitespace

I'm writing a for loop in bash to run a command and I need to add a comma after one of my variables. I can't seem to do this without an extra space added. When I move "," right next to `$bams` then it outputs `*.sorted`,

```
#!/bin/bash

bams=*.sorted

for i in $bams
   do echo $bams ","
done;
```

Output should be this:

```
'file1.sorted','file2.sorted','file3.sorted'
```

The eventual end goal is to be able to insert a list of files into a `--flag` in the format above. Not sure how to do that either.

Comment: That's actually an interesting issue. I checked in the bash manual and from what I see there, it looks like `echo $bams","` should still expand to a list of filenames, so I'm not sure why it's doing exactly what it's doing.

Comment: If you want to run `--flag 'foo','bar','baz'`, that's actually 100% identical to `--flag 'foo,bar,baz'`: The program being invoked has no way of knowing if the commas were included in the quotes or not, because they're removed by the calling shell before that program is started. And if your `foo,bar,baz` string is stored in a variable named `var`, then you'd run `--flag "$var"` (with *double* quotes, not single ones).

Comment: See [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) (*I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!*)

Comment: @DavidZ, `bams=*.sorted; echo $bams","` is expanding `*.sorted,` as a glob. You don't have any files with commas on the end of their names, so there aren't any matches, so it doesn't expand. What in the manual did you take to indicate that behavior would be anything else?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Ah, I guess I got mixed up about something. That explains it.

Comment: Your edit makes it clear that you just asked the wrong question (or, rather, a question to which having a correct answer doesn't help you in your real-world situation). The answer to this -- after that question has been correctly answered -- is to ask a new, *different* question, one which has an answer that *will* help you; not to edit your question into a different one (thereby post-facto making previously received answers incorrect). I've fixed up the formatting on your edit, but just to have an example on how to format code clearly.

Comment: That said, the answer to the question you *wanted* to ask is: `for i in ../annotations/*.bed; do bedtools multicov -bams *.sorted -bed "$i" >"$i.multicov"`

Comment: (Rolled back to undo the editing-into-a-completely-different-question; see the edit history if you're interested in aforementioned formatting guidance).

Comment: @Charles Duffy In regards to the formating guideline thank you for that information as I am new to Stackoverflow. As for the answer to the question, a wildcard will not work with the particular program because of how the program processes it. This is very particular for the program i'm trying to use which is why I need it to be text separated in a particular manner into the flag. The individuals who gave the answer were going about it in the direction that I wanted.

Comment: @JSBrewer, the program being invoked (in your case `bedtools`) has no way of knowing if a wildcard was used to the shell or not. On UNIX -- unlike Windows -- wildcards are replaced with filenames *by the shell* before a program is invoked.

Comment: All a program gets on invocation is an array of C strings, without any means of knowing how each string in that array was derived -- if it was entered by the user in quotes, if it came from a wildcard expansion, if it came from an array, etc.

Comment: You might try taking advantage of `set -x`, which tells the shell to log every command it runs. Thus, if `foo *.sorted` and `foo 'file1.sorted' 'file2.sorted'` print the same thing when the shell has run `set -x`, that's conclusive evidence that they really do run the exact same thing (and discrepancies in that output will make it easier to explain to someone else what you're trying to accomplish by *not* using certain syntax).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, a literal answer (if your goal were to generate a string of the form `'foo','bar','baz'`, rather than to run a program with a command line equivalent to `somecommand --flag='foo','bar','baz'`, which is quite different):

```
shopt -s nullglob               # generate a null result if no matches exist
printf -v var "'%s'," *.sorted  # put list of files, each w/ a comma, in var
echo "${var%,}"                 # echo contents of var, with last comma removed
```

Or, if you don't need the literal single quotes (and if you're passing your result to another program on its command line with the single quotes being syntactic rather than literal, you **absolutely** don't want them):

```
files=( *.sorted )               # put *.sorted in an array
IFS=,                            # set the comma character as the field separator
somecommand --flag "${files[*]}" # run your program with the comma-separated list
```

Comment: Your script above did the trick. I had to just make one minor change which was to add the grave character around echo inside the bedtools command. Heres the final solution. <br/> `shopt -s nullglob printf -v var "%s " *.sorted  for i in ../annotations/*
do bedtools multicov -bams `echo "${var%}"` -bed $i > $i.multicov.2.0 done;`

Comment: You don't need that `echo` at all, *or* backticks. `bedtools multicon -bams "${var% }" -bed "$i" >"$i.multicov.2.0"` will do.

Comment: That's assuming that `bedtool` takes exactly one string on its argument list with all your filenames in it separated by spaces, vs one string per file. If you wanted one string for file, you could just put `*.sorted` on the command line and get the exact same effect.

Comment: BTW, all the quotes (around `"$i"`, etc) are necessary to get correct behavior with unusual/surprising filenames. Leaving them out when you think you don't need them will bite you eventually -- I've seen a multi-TB data loss event caused by someone thinking no filename in a given directory "could ever have" non-hex characters.

Comment: Very odd. I did it as you described without the back ticks and echo to no avail. Not sure what bedtools is doing, since if I run without using backticks and echo, it wont add the file list into the flag the way that bedtools wants it.

Comment: Can you show how `bash -x` (or `set -x` in your script) logs the command being run each way? That is, a successful manual invocation, and then what's done by the code I provided, and perhaps also with the code you're running above?

Comment: Good tip on the quotation marks. Was not aware of that.

Comment: (BTW, if you *just* have backticks, and no quotes around them, in your "final solution", that means you're having the shell split your string out into a list of arguments and pass each argument separately; *if* that's actually the case, then there was no point to putting them into a string in the first place, and the list would be more appropriately stored in an array if you need to store it at all).

Comment: (the `set -x` logs with the backticks-running-echo approach should be exactly identical to what they'd be with a wildcard in use in that case, as well).

Comment: Ok. I did this and saved the output to a file. How is best to send you the output? Also Stackoverflow is yelling at me about extended discussions in comments

Comment: Would you mind a [gist](https://gist.github.com/)? Those can be checked out/updated/&c. with git, and the comment support is liable to come in handy.

Comment: Note the single quotes in the output. I didnt see it until I combed through them side by side.  [github] https://gist.github.com/anonymous/a6dcd86fec73e0f4836086feb216770b

Comment: Thanks -- following up using the comment functionality in the gist.

Answer (score 0):

try this -

```
lst=$( echo *.sorted | sed 's/ /,/g' ) # stack filenames with commas
echo $lst
```

if you really need the single-ticks around each filename, then

```
lst="'$( echo *.sorted | sed "s/ /','/g" )'" # commas AND quotes
```

Comment: was just trying to show use in place with a --flag, but you're right. 
Too much noise.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

bams=*.sorted

for i in $bams
   do flag+="${flag:+,}'$i'"
done

echo $flag
```